# What is the expected number of bins that ends not being empty?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider a situation in which 8 distinct balls are distributed among 6 distinct bins. What is the expected number of bins that ends not being empty ?

---

Can I apply Sterling formula of 2nd kind here ?

Comment: Why not simply calculate $P(X)$ for $X\in[0,5]$ and then calculate $E(X)$?

Comment: @barakmanos Actually I don't know what is the meaning of expectation in terms of probability. But, I tried it by sterling formula of 2nd kind and got the answer. If possible, Can you please provide me some source or link, so that I can learn the expectation. It would help me learning this easy method very much ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ bin.  Thus $X_i=1$ if that bin contains a ball, and $0$ otherwise.  By [Linearity of Expectation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function), the answer you seek is $$E=\sum_{i=1}^6E[X_i]$$ Of course, $E[X_i]$ is just the probability that the $i^{th}$ bin is non-empty, hence $E[X_i]=1-\left(\frac 56\right)^8$.  Thus $$E=6\times \left[1-\left(\frac 56\right)^8\right]=4.604591764$$